# Get class name from jquery code

Tags: jquery

Here i have created list using ul tag in jquery code......
I want to get access to those list using class name how can i get it.....

Here is the java script code....
i want to access those list items using class name......

```js
var listItem = "<ul class='list-style' id="+"'"+eId+"'"+" ><li class='list-name'>" + employees[id-1].name + "</li><li class='list-phone-email'>" + employees[id-1].email + "</li><li class='list-phone-email'>+91 " + employees[id-1].mobile + "</ul>";
```

Comment: Whats the issue? Can you do `$('.list-name')`?

Comment: no, i cant get access with that line

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jQuery object using [`jQuery(html \[,ownerDocument\])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2), then use various methods to target elements.

```
$(listItem).find('.list-name')
```

```js
var listItem = "<ul class='list-style'><li class='list-name'>Satpal Singh</li><li class='list-phone-email'>Not Required</li></ul>";
console.log($(listItem).find('.list-name').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to access those list items using class name......

```
 $('ul.list-name');
```

> Get class name from jquery code

```
 $('ul').attr('class');
```

To get the contents in the `li` tags by their class name then

```
var name = $('li.list-name').text();
var phoneEmail = $('li.list-phone-email').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

`$(".list-name").each(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});`